# How to enable ido-mode forever?

Tags: ido

I want to have it enabled every time I open emacs and not type `M-x ido-mode` each time I open it.

Comment: Please have a look at the [Emacswiki node for "Interactively Do Things"](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings).  The first bullet tells you how to activate it in your init file.  (I found this with a [google search for "emacs ido-mode"](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+ido-mode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).)

Comment: @Dan Thanks it worked now, I don't know what I did before that didn't work. Do you think I should delete this question or answer it?

Comment: It's possible you hadn't restarted Emacs after adding it to your init file.

Comment: I'm tired that's probably it ;) @Dan

Comment: @Dan Actually I found the problem, ido-mode doesn't work while using ibuffer and I was always testing it while on ibuffer of course (facepalm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've decided to answer my question as some other noobs like me could have the same problem. Just follow the following steps(everything that I'm going to say is on these links https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings or https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile):

1. Open your init file (for GnuEmacs it's ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el)
2. In that file add this code and save the file:

   ```
   (require 'ido)
   (ido-mode t)
   ```
3. Restart emacs, or to avoid restarting for current session, select the above two lines, and use

   ```
   M-x eval-region
   ```
4. Then do `M-x customize-group RET ido RET` and configure ido-mode

Also don't forget that ido-mode doesn't work while on ibuffer like I did.
**Thanks to @dan**

Comment: For the record, if you use `(ido-everywhere)`, then ido will work in ibuffer too.