# How to enable the superword minor mode globally?

Tags: minor-mode

I am just wondering how to enable the `superword-mode` globally?

I tried to enable it following the answers found here:

[How to enable ido-mode forever?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22084)

, using:

```
(require 'superword-mode)
(superword-mode t)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, superword-mode
```

I am using Emacs 26 under Ubuntu 18.04. Using `M-x superword-mode` manually enables the mode right. But I just don't want to enable the mode every time.

I also tried `(superword-mode t)` alone, but it does not work and emacs is still stopping at underscores when moving forward a word (`M-f`).

I guess a related question is, is there a generic way of enabling a minor mode?

**-- Update --**

I tried:

```
(require 'superword)
```

as suggested in the comments. But I am still getting the same error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/user/.emacs.d/init.el’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, superword
```

This is with `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30)`

Comment: Try (require 'superword) instead.

Comment: See `C-h f require`.

Comment: @Dan `superword-mode` is defined in the library `subword` of Emacs 26.2 so it must be `(require 'subword)` instead of `(require 'superword)`. On the other hand `subword` is bundled with Emacs 26.2 and the mode function it is autoloaded so `require` should not be necessary. No idea what is going on there. Maybe, the OP tried to install some other shadowing version and that failed. E.g., an empty `subword.el` somewhere with higher prio in `load-path` would display such effects.

Comment: My last comment implies that you should definitively test with `emacs -Q`. Note for Windows-users: You can start `emacs -Q` from a running Emacs by `M-& emacs -Q <RET>`.

Comment: It could also mean that the autoload files are not correctly provided by the installation. In that case `(require 'subword)` should help. But, you should seriously check your installation in that case.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks. I added `(require 'subword)`. The `require` works fine, but the `(superword-mode t)` still does nothing. `emacs -Q` reports not error, but `emacs -Q a.txt` still behaves the same: manually enabling `M-x superword-mode` works, but changing init.el does not.

Comment: I did not address your question in my comments but only the initialization error you are getting. That is the actual strange thing since `superword-mode` is an **autoloaded** function. If you cannot use `superword-mode` without the `require` something must be wrong with your installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am just wondering how to enable the `superword-mode` globally?

Use `(global-superword-mode t)`.