# How do I hook fundamental-mode and all modes derived from it for modifying syntax for underscores

Tags: syntax-table

Here is the definition of `fundamental-mode`:

```
(defun fundamental-mode ()
  "Major mode not specialized for anything in particular.
Other major modes are defined by comparison with this one."
  (interactive)
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (run-mode-hooks))
```

There does not seem to be a `fundamental-mode-hook` defined.

I would like to call some code for all "fundamental-mode" buffers *and* all derived modes from it, *without* having to itemize all such modes and explicitly call `add-hook` on all of their mode functions.

Is there a way or am I stuck paying the itemization cost?  If yes, then how do I do this inside all modes:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

because after decades of Emacs usage, I've finally grown tired of my cursor getting hung up on every single underscore for every time I use `M-f` (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>), across all *new* modes that are invented and that I install into my setup.

Comment: Consider wrapping your cursor movement function(s) with a temporary / custom syntax table (or modification thereof) that will be in effect for only the duration of the cursor movement, and forget about hooks and modifications of fundamental-mode and the like.  E.g., `with-syntax-table` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Functions.html

Comment: Not posting as an asnwer because the question is more general, but [global-superword-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51020/11725) can be a solution of the issue that you describe at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st:** Dealing with your actual problem of setting the syntax for `?_` in modes derived from `fundamental-mode`.

There are no commands setting the syntax table in `fundamental-mode`. Therefore, it uses the `(standard-syntax-table)`. If the syntax for `?_` is not defined in a mode it uses the entry in its inherited syntax table. By default, `(standard-syntax-table)` is inherited. Since there are no circular references for syntax tables `(standard-syntax-table)` is eventually the fallback for all modes.

If we assume that modes setting the syntax for `?_` do it for a good reason it should be sufficient to use the following line in your init files:

```el
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ " " (standard-syntax-table))
```

(This works at least in Emacs 27.1.90.)

**2nd:** The user is not supposed to customize `fundamental-mode`. So there is no hook for that mode.
Furthermore, `fundamental-mode` does not really play a role in the inheritance hierarchy. For all modes but `fundamental-mode` itself `(derived-mode-p 'fundamental-mode)` evaluates to `nil`.

Nevertheless, there is `after-change-major-mode-hook` that is run at the very end of major mode functions. That allows you to do general settings for all modes.

Comment: +500: For my goal, treating underscores as a part of words globally was facilitated by `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" (standard-syntax-table))`.  Thanks Tobias!